# How to get the share(Post) photo URl or link with facebook SDk?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to take Url of Facebook post image. I am successfully posting the photo on Facebook with the *logInWithPublishPermissions* but I want the link or Url of the post image in call back....

```
 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .setCaption("VodaFone Rakshavandhan!")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();



ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(FacebookShareActivity.this);
    shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);

    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

            Log.e("@@@result", String.valueOf(result));

        /*  "/"+mFBID+"_"+postid+"?fields=link,message",*/
            String postid=result.getPostId().toString();

        mUrlFb="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid="+postid;
            Log.e("@@@mUrlFb",mUrlFb);

                GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
                        accessToken,
                    "/"+mFBID+"_"+postid,
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {


        Log.e("@@response", String.valueOf(response));

                        }



    });


            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,link,message");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        /*  new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    result.getPostId(),
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.e("@@response", String.valueOf(response));
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();*/




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

I am getting the Response from this Graph Request

```
  {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: 
 {"id":"104752556880730_105851436770842"}, error: null}
```

any help appreciate.

Comment: You need to take that post id you get in the response, and make an API request using that, requesting the `permalink_url` field for that post.

Comment: Read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) a lil bit carefully, there's a field named "link" - A link to the photo on Facebook

Comment: @CBroe thanks so much Sir it is working well. I pass the only permalink_url in the request it will response me which I want thanks once again.

Comment: Hi, arjun, how do you get postId? Mine always null :(

Comment: @Freya You need to take the permission of publish_action from facebook and than you use the upper code In register callback of share dialog

Comment: Log.e("@@@result", String.valueOf(result));

        /*  "/"+mFBID+"_"+postid+"?fields=link,message",*/
            String postid=result.getPostId().toString();

Comment: did you submit your app to facebook for review to use publish_action?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android submit your submission on your create app on facebook

Comment: so the getPostId wont work if we don't submit submission for review on facebook?

Comment: Yes.. You need to submit the application by this code and give response error which u take with onError(FacebookException e)  "e" you get the permission denial of publish_action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special Thanks to @CBroe

Only Add the parameter `**permalink_url**`

```
 parameters.putString("fields", "id,link,message,permalink_url");
```